# query in table pivot laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have two tables and one pivot table which has

- FK_idStore
- FK_idEmployee
- dateChange

My model store:

```
   public function employee(){

   return $this->belongsToMany(empleado::class,'employee_store', 'fk_idStore','fk_idEmployee')        
  ->withPivot('dateChange');
  }
```

the result:

[image: Resultado]

I need to show the last store where an employee was.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$store = Store::findOrFail($id)->employee->latest();
```

Or:

```
$store = Store::findOrFail($id)->employee->->sortBy('dateChange', 'desc')->first();
```

Comment: i need show a list every employee that belongs to Store. thanks

Comment: @Edu27 you said you need the last store, ok then you need $store= Store::findOrFail($id)->employee;

Comment: of course, i said last store, but in the pivot table there are repeat records, example employe1 - store 1 date 2018 // employe1 - store2 - date 2019 // employe1-store3 -date2020 (i need show ONLY it's actuall store), please

Comment: Laravel knows that you have the pivot table and automatically get the data from it, but you should have the employee function inside the Store model, and the same for the Employee model you should have store function inside it. and inside the migration make sure you have settled the foreign keys correctly.

Comment: All is ok, however how can i FILTER  the results of ( $store= Store::findOrFail($id)->employee)  without  REPEAT records?  i use 'dateChange' for i know the last store.

Comment: @Edu27 you should eliminate the duplicates and never store ones inside your database. put this constraint in the migration that create your pivot table $table->unique(['idEmployee', 'fk_idStore']);

Comment: i did because I need to know what store the employee was in. With 'dateChange' i make a HISTORiCAL

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pivot table is the Store, and that you need the last record of each employee in each store, use:

```
public function employee(){
    return Employe_Store::all()->groupBy('fk_idEmployee')->max('dateChange');
}
```

Comment: @Edu27 let me know if that's not exactly what you need.

Comment: My 3 tables are: Employee, Store and Employe_Store(this is the pivot table), please chek it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61440019/select-data-no-repeat-in-pivot-table

Comment: Ok, I edited my response here and posted there. Test if it works for you.