# select data no repeat in pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have 2 table and 1 pivot table which I use as table Historical, the column 'dateChange' indicated the store where is the employee, because I use *Orderby ('dateChange','DESC')*. All is ok, however how can I FILTER the results in my controller?  without REPEAT records?.
I need to show all the employees that belong to a unique store.  I repeat again:  *I use 'dateChange' for I know the last store.* help me, please. Thanks

Pivot Table (employee_store)

- FK_idStore
- FK_idEmployee
- dateChange

Table Employee

- idEmployee
- Name

Table Store

- idStore
- nameStore
- direction

Model

```
public function employee(){    
   return $this->belongsToMany(employee::class,'employee_store', 'fk_idStore','fk_idEmployee')        
  ->withPivot('dateChange')->orderBy('dateChange','DESC');
```

Controller

```
$store= Store::findOrFail($id)->employee
return $store
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
public function employee(){
return $this->belongsToMany(employee::class,..
```

to

```
public function employees(){
return $this->belongsToMany(Employee::class,..
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use eager loading:

in your Controller

```
$store= Store::findOrFail($id)->with('employee')->get();
return $store;
```

more details in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

To get the last record of each employee in each store, use:

```
public function employee(){
    return Employe_Store::all()->groupBy('fk_idEmployee')->max('dateChange');
}
```